# Why b not be constructed to `BigInt<8>` to plus a?

Tags: c++11

I have a class

```
template <int n> BigInt
```

In this class have method constructor

```
template<int m> BigInt(const BigInt<m>& b)
```

and

```
operator + (const BigInt& b)
```

When I use operator+, example:

```
BigInt<8> a;
BigInt<6> b;
BigInt<8> c = a+b;
```

Why b not be constructed to `BigInt<8>` to plus a?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem. Show a full self-contained example.

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a81cefd278f27e57)